# Is fuzzy matching with RubyGems gem install version possible?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to specify that you want the latest version of gem within semantic versioning constraints?  For instance, if I wanted the most recent version of the `foo` gem within the 2.x.x set of available gems, is there a way to have RubyGems install whatever the latest version before 3.0.0?  Hypothetically something along the lines of: `gem install foo --semantic-version 2` might make sense.

Comment: I don't know much, but [bundler](http://bundler.io/) may handle that.

Comment: We don't really use bundler very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what pessimistic version constraints are for:

```
gem install --version '~> 2.0'
```

Comment: Cool.  I knew you could do that in bundler but hadn't found documentation that you could do it on with `gem install`